# IIS 7.5 Custom Errors and URL Rewrite

Tags: iis, iis-7, asp-classic, url-rewriting

I was looking at both of these options in IIS to try and accomplish the compounding of querystrings to appear like file directories.. like this:

`/search/`

`/search/janice`

`/search/janice/cooper`

Whereas the original URL is something like `/search?fname=janice&lname=cooper`

I tried the URL Rewrite method, but it doesn't allow optional fields (for querystrings)

I tried custom 404 error, and it gets the REFERER of the original script, but the script itself cannot accessed by URL, only be referral, so this won't work either..

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to accomplish something like this?

Comment: pls confirm this is classic asp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method to achieve it: [URL Rewriting in classic ASP](http://asp.johnavis.com/blog/default.asp?id=19)

The best way to achieve the concatenating of query strings to end up as URL routing is to upgrae the project to be ASP.Net and use [ASP.NET Routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx).

If you are in the middle of upgrading and wish to be able to switch over easily without broken links and losing google ranking when links change is to use [Helicon ISAPI Rewrite](http://www.isapirewrite.com/)

Comment: Your first example explains.. I guess i have to get the referring page from the query_string.. Odd, but it works.. Thanks!